# Delete apps from previous Apple ID and set iPhone to factory seeting

Tags: iphone, apple-id

I sold my iPhone to my friend and she used her Apple ID to sync some apps and music, but after a few days she gave it back to me. Now I have 2 questions:

1. How can I delete all her apps and Apple ID from my phone? (I mean I need to reset to original factory settings to use my own apps and Apple ID.)
2. I have a backup from my phone. How can I sync my own apps and use my own Apple ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset to factory settings, in your iPhone go to Settings → General → Reset → Erase All Content and Settings. It ask for confirmation twice.

To restore a previous backup, you have a couple of options:

1. Connect your iPhone to iTunes and you will see a Restore Backup... button on the iPhone Summary tab.
2. If you start your phone without iTunes, once you enter your Apple ID and password you will be prompted to restore a backup (if you have one stored on iCloud).